# Is an Application object more than just a container / module?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I've been rewriting an application of mine using Marionette, but I'm a bit confused.

In every usage I've seen, the `Marionette.Application` object appears to just be used as a container / top-level module (which it is) and nothing more:

```
App = new Marionette.Application();

App.module('myModule', function(args) { /* ... */ });

App.on('event', function() {});
```

While I have been testing, it has become necessary to occasionally create a new `Application` instance and pass in different options. Because of this setup, it means I will need to also call the necessary functions (e.g. `addInitializer`, `addRegions`, `.module`) on my new instance.

This is in contrast to other objects (like Models or Views) where most (if not all) of the configuration takes place within the configuration options, before an object has even been instantiated:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'different-id',
    defaults: {
        'content-type': 'product'
    },

    sync: function() {
        // override a function
        return false;
    }
});
```

Unlike these objects, we *must* instantiate the `Application` before doing any configuration.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the `Application` object? Is it just supposed to be a generic top-level container?

Comment: Err... that's a mistake. I'll edit that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application` is the centerpiece of your SPA, and you should have exactly one instance running on any given page. Each of your site's major capabilities will branch from the App in the form of `Modules`; any coordination that happens between modules should be set up at the `Application` level. Generally speaking, you'll define your app, define a bunch of modules, add initializers to setup comms between the modules, and then `start` the application, which will automatically trigger the startup of all modules (unless configured otherwise).

If you find yourself using more than one application on a single page, you probably haven't abstracted enough; the App really should only contain logic that will be shared across modules; if each module is completely self-contained, then you're right - your App is likely to look like a very generic container.

HTH...

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [doc](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md)

> The Application is meant to be instantiated directly, although you can extend it to add your own functionality.

It is used as the top-most level container and help to provide facilities to 'tie' all sub-components together.

Comment: While this answer is helpful, I'm looking for more insight into why the `Application` object is so different from other components.

Comment: Application object provides a way to tie most if not all usages like addInitializer, addRegions, vent, ... as you mentioned. So for most application no need to 'customize' it as opposite to like backbone objects, they are meant to provide the basic 'facilities' to manage your data and also add your own facilities as well.